# Most efficient way to calculate Fibonacci sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o, fibonacci

I'm attempting to get better with optimizing algorithms and understanding big-o, etc.

I threw together the below function to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number. This works (for a reasonably high input). My question is, how can I improve this function? What are the drawbacks of calculating the Fibonacci sequence this way?

```
function fibo(n) {  

    var i;
    var resultsArray = [];  

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            resultsArray.push(0);
        } else if (i === 1) {
            resultsArray.push(1);
        } else {
            resultsArray.push(resultsArray[i - 2] + resultsArray[i - 1]);
        }
    }

    return resultsArray[n];
}
```

I believe my big-o for time is O(n), but my big-o for space is O(n^2) due to the array I created. Is this correct?

Comment: I suggest you post this on: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or maybe: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wrote an article on the Fibonacci sequence recently in the context of interview questions, focusing on complexity. You might find this useful looking at some of the implementations and their characteristics. http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2013/09/algorithm-fibonacci-sequence.html

Comment: Why would ECMAScript/JavaScript be special?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't have an *Array* then you save on memory and `.push` calls

```
function fib(n) {
    var a = 0, b = 1, c;
    if (n < 3) {
        if (n < 0) return fib(-n);
        if (n === 0) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    while (--n)
        c = a + b, a = b, b = c;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You missed `if(n == 0) return 0;`

Comment: @instead I also missed negative `n`, added these cases now

Comment: Definitely not the most efficient because it calculates manually. You can calculate F(2n) and F(2n+1) knowing F(n) and F(n+1) with a handful of operations instead of hundreds of thousands of operations if you are playing with big numbers. Edit: https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Answer (score 3):

Performance Fibonacci:

```
    var memo = {};
    var countInteration = 0;
    var fib = function (n) {
        if (memo.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
            return memo[n];
        }
        countInteration++;
        console.log("Interation = " + n);
        if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
            result = 1;
        } else {
            result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
        memo[n] = result;
        return result;
    }
    //output `countInteration` = parameter `n`
```